# python Как получить имени переменной в виде строки?

Tags: python, переменные

Избитый вопрос, мне нужно получить имя переменной в виде строки. Понимаю, что у переменных нет функции **name** - она в коде только для того, чтобы было понятней, что я хочу получить. Суть в том, что мне нужно только ИМЯ переменной чтобы получить доступ к базе данных по словарю. Мне глубоко фиолетово на что эта переменная ссылается, это совершенно не важно, только имя и всё. Нужно получить аналог W = F['spisok'] используя "x".

```
import shelve

spisok = 12345

def ABC(x):
    F = shelve.open('База данных')
    W = F[x.__name__]

Q = ABC(spisok)
```

Comment: Это совершенно бессмысленно, потому что вы сами пишите что получит функция, поэтому надо просто добавить кавачки

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string

Comment: `"Мне глубоко фиолетово на что эта переменная ссылается, это совершенно не важно, только имя и всё."` Если бы мне пришлось работать с подобным кодом, написанным коллегой, то я бы очень постарался либо научить его нормально использовать переменные либо сделать так, чтобы я никогда больше не работал с этим коллегой и его кодом :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чем плох такой вариант?

```
def DEF(x_name):
    F = shelve.open('База данных')
    W = F[x_name]
    return ...

Q = DEF('spisok')
```

Сравните с оригинальным вариантом:

```
def ABC(x):
    F = shelve.open('База данных')
    W = F[x.__name__]
    return ...

Q = ABC(spisok)
```

Замена в вызывающем коде `ABC(spisok)` -> `DEF('spisok')`. Какие могут быть недостатки у второго вызова в сравнении с первым?

Шутки ради `ABC` можно **кривовато** реализовать так:

```
def ABC(x):
    for k, v in inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals.items():
        if v == x:
            F = shelve.open('База данных')
            W = F[k]
            return ...
            
spisok = 12345
Q = ABC(spisok)
```

Это работает но зачем? И что делать с `ABC(a + b)`?

Comment: Спасибо, Станислав, кажется я патологически туп, пол дня думал, как имя переменной выразить в виде строки - изначально написать в кавычках. Danis прошу простить не сразу понял.